# Can´t implicity convert string to viewmodel

Tags: wpf, model, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I have a program that should display files in a list view.
My code looks like this and I get error "cannot convert from string into viewmodel" If I change Additem(movies.MovieName) to Additem(movies) I dont get a error but it only writes out "MoviePlayerModule.ViewModelsMoviesViewModel.
I want it to write the file name that it gets from movies.MovieName = filename;

```
 private void ReadMediaFile()
    {
       var movies = new MoviesViewModel();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Paths.Root);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
           var filename = Path.GetFileName(file); 
          movies.MovieName = filename;
        };

        AddItem(movies.MovieName);     
    }
```

In filename it says: "ATTV_bog.mpg" and that is the mpg file thats in the folder.

If I change the code so it looks like this:

```
 var moviee = new MoviesViewModel();



        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:/Users/v80770/Desktop/Movies");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filename = file;
            moviee.MovieName = filename;
        };

        AddItem(moviee);
```

The output just is MoviePlayer.ViewModels.MoviesViewModel

In my View the code is like this:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MovieName"  Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>
```

And I´m using CaliburnMicro.

ViewModel class:

```
 public class MoviesViewModel : TreeViewNode<MoviesViewModel>
{
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClassName.MovieplayerModule.Views.MoviesView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MovieName"  Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>
```

And AddItem method, located in TreeViewBase.cs

```
public void AddItem(T item)
    {
        _dispatcher.SmartInvoke(() => Items.Add(item));
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your setting the same property each iteration of the loop, perhaps you `movies.MovieName` should be a list which you append to each loop iteration? Or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: Set a breakpoint there and look whats inside of `filename` and give us some more infos about the error you get

Comment: are you trying to add to a collection of strings? or a collection of MovieViewModels?  that additem at the end seems like it should be AddItem(movies) and not moves.MovieName from the error you are getting.

Comment: I have updated my question whit new information now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the actual `Movie` object to the `ListView` using `AddItem(moviee)` and then use the `DisplayMemberPath` property to specify that you want to display the value of the `MovieName` property:

```
<ListView ... DisplayMemberPath="MovieName" .... />
```

Comment: Itryed edit my code to ListView and Displaymemberpath but it still is the same output

Comment: Please post your `ListView`, `AddItem` method and `MoviesViewModel` class.

Comment: Updated post with view, additemclass and viewmodel

Comment: What is `Items` and how do you bind to it in the view?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had comment out Items in another view and forgor about it. Now it all works :D